# Have to go backwards. How to fix code written with asp.net 4.0 to run under asp.net 2.0 framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have just begun a new job. I am having to fix/finish a web application that was begun on Visual Studio 3.0 and written for asp.net 2.0 framework. As I opened this application in their current Visual Studio version of 2010, it converted all code to .net 4.0 before I realized that the intranet server that this app runs on only has .net 2.0. My boss does not want to update the server because this is also their development server and most of their applications are on this server in a 2.0 environment.

I was able to convert the code back to 2.0 by changing the target framework, but now I am getting a bunch of System.Data.... and System.Web.... errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you tell what visual studio changed about the project by looking at the differences in your source control?

Comment: ASP.NET 3.5(App pool framework 2.0) did not have major differences against 4.0. If you changed the target framework  what are the errors? Please share the last bottom 3

Comment: What is Visual Studio 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

You could be a bit more specific and actually post the errors here.

There are a number of significant differences between CLR versions 2.0 and 4.0, and a lot of new features were added to ASP.NET for version 4 as well.

However, the project conversion tool is not going to make changes to your code or markup, it's most likely just going to upgrade references assemblies, for example System.Data from v2 to v4. I suspect this is the problem having downgraded to v2 again; references cannot be loaded. Do you get any yellow icons on top of assemblies in the "References" folder ? This indicates they cannot be loaded.

By the way there is *absolutely* no risk in installing .NET 4 side by side with 2.0 onto a server, I have done it many times and observed that all .NET 2 applications continued to function as normal.